# protoBuf slower and larger than BinaryFormatter

Tags: .net, serialization, protobuf-net

In a simple test, protoBuf v2 is much slower than BinaryFormatter, when the principal data is `Dictionary<int, string>`.  protoBuf time is 931ms, and the stream size is 7,950,000.  BinaryFormatter time is 52ms, and the stream size is 193,798. So it's a big difference.

Here's the full test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace SerDeser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int HOW_MANY = 10000;
            var data = new TestClass[HOW_MANY];
            var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
             for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                d1.Add(i, i.ToString());
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++)
            {
                data[i] = new TestClass() {InnerData = d1};
            }
            SerDeser(data, "BinaryFormatter", false);
            SerDeser(data, "ProtoBuf", true);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SerDeser(TestClass[] data, string label, bool useProtoBuf)
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();
            IFormatter formatter = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                timer.Start();
                if (useProtoBuf)
                {
                    Serializer.Serialize<TestClass[]>(ms, data);
                }
                else
                {
                    formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(ms, data);
                }
                TestClass[] clone = null;
                var serTime = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                timer.Reset();
                timer.Start();
                ms.Position = 0;
                if (useProtoBuf)
                {
                    clone = Serializer.Deserialize<TestClass[]>(ms);
                }
                else
                {
                    clone = formatter.Deserialize(ms) as TestClass[];
                }
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: ser {1}ms; deser {2}ms; total {3}ms; length {4}", label, serTime, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, serTime + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, ms.Length));
                if (clone.Length != data.Length) Console.WriteLine("length error.");
                if (clone[1].InnerData.Count != data[1].InnerData.Count) Console.WriteLine("Content error 1");
                if (clone[1].InnerData[1] != data[1].InnerData[1]) Console.WriteLine("Content error 2");
            }
        }

    }

    [ProtoContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
        }
        [ProtoMemberAttribute(1)] public Dictionary<int, string> InnerData;

    }

}
```

I create an array of 10,000 of these, and the InnerData property of each of them is a dictionary with 100 entries.    My test serializes and deserializes the array.

For the protobuf test, I simply use Serializer.Serialize(ms) where ms is a MemoryStream. (and Serializer.DeSerialize to deserialize).  I can post my test driver code if asked.

So my question is, under what conditions should I expect protoBuf to be slower than or faster than BinaryFormatter?

Comment: Using that class, I get the exact opposite results: MSBF == 50ms and 230,587 bytes; PBN == 6 to 10ms, 108,767 bytes.  For the very first run, PBN is slower (123 ms).  PBN should always be smaller because it is using integer tokens rather than the lengthy prop names that BF uses.   What did you store in the dictionary for the string?

Comment: I populate the dictionary with key=i;value=i.ToString(), for i=1..100.

Comment: I've updated my post with the full repro code.

Comment: And the moral of the story is: beware simple tests... they can be deceptive if they don't represent something realistic ;p

Comment: I still get (much) better PBN results: BF == 3200ms and 23,821,452 bytes vs PBN @ 300ms and 7,950,00 bytes. your BF size of 193,798 looks suspect for 100 x 10,000 int-string pairs.  You might want to deserialize to a new var and see if everything is making the round trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are repeating the exact same `InnerData` instance every time. `BinaryFormatter` always tracks references. protobuf-net *can* track references, but it does not do so by default, because the google specification has no notion of this.

However, I doubt that serializing the same instance lots of times is a useful test - it rarely represents real usage for either serializer.

To give a realistic test, generate a different `InnerData` instance per `HOW_MANY`, and also ensure that the `string`s are different string instances each time (again, `BinaryFormatter` will track references on `string`s too).

Or alternatively, enable reference-tracking in protobuf-net. Unfortunately, you can't easily do this for `string`s that are the immediate children of `Dictionary<int,string>`.

Here's my change:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int HOW_MANY = 10000;
    var data = new TestClass[HOW_MANY];
    for (var i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> d1 = InventData();
        data[i] = new TestClass() { InnerData = d1 };
    }
    SerDeser(data, "BinaryFormatter", false);
    SerDeser(data, "ProtoBuf", true);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Dictionary<int, string> InventData()
{
    var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        d1.Add(i, i.ToString());
    }

    return d1;
}
```

with results (I added thousand separators for easy comparison):

```
BinaryFormatter: ser 3,413ms; deser 30,833ms; total 34,246ms; length 23,821,447
ProtoBuf: ser 450ms; deser 591ms; total 1,041ms; length 7,950,000
```

I know which I'd prefer!